# Convex minorant is borel measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is a question from a real analysis prelim exam. Let $L_{a,b}(x)=ax+b$ for some $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded below. The problem does not say whether or not $f$ is measurable (Borel or Lebesgue). We define $A=\{(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2: L_{a,b}(z)\leq f(z)\quad \forall z\in \mathbb{R}\}$. Then put
\begin{equation}
\tilde{f}(x)=\sup_{(a,b)\in A}L_{a,b}(x).
\end{equation}
Show that $\tilde{f}$ is Borel measurable. The problem says that $\tilde{f}$ is called the convex minorant of $f$, and it is the largest convex function less than $f$ everywhere.

My approach was to try to see if it was enough to replace $A$ by a countable subset, maybe $\mathbb{Q}^2\cap A$ and see if this changes the values of $\tilde{f}$ anywhere except a set of measure zero. Then $\tilde{f}$ would be the pointwise sup of a countable set of continuous (and hence Borel measurable) functions, which would therefore be Borel measurable. I couldn't see why this is possible. If anyone has any hints, or indeed could let me know whether $f$ must indeed be measurable and this was just omitted, then that would be appreciated.

I guess another way to do it would be to show that $\tilde{f}$ is indeed convex as the problem states, because then it has to be continuous also and hence Borel measurable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convexity is not hard to show: Fix $\lambda\in [0,1]$ and $(a,b)\in A$ (notice that $L_{a,b}$ is convex), then
$$
L_{a,b}(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\leq \lambda L_{a,b}(x)+(1-\lambda) L_{a,b}(y)\leq \lambda\tilde{f}( x) +\tilde{f}(1-\lambda)y).
$$
Now take the supremum over all $(a,b)\in A$ to conclude.

On the other hand, you can also get measurability directly by noting that since $L_{a,b}$ is continuous, then $\tilde{f}$, being the supremum of continuous functions, is lower semicontinuous (i.e. the set $\{ x: \tilde{f}>a\}$ is open for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$ (also notice that $\tilde{f}$ is everywhere finite, since $f$ is bounded below)).

Comment: The convexity approach is indeed very simple! I understand. I have never seen lower semi-continuity before and this was not covered in the course or mentioned in the prelim syllabus, so I don't think I could use that result. Seems like a very useful concept though as essentially being slightly stronger than Borel measurability and slightly weaker than continuity, if I understand correctly.

Comment: It's indeed a intermediate concept between those two notions, but I'd say it's closer to continuity; for instance $f$ is l.s.c. if and only if for any $x$ it holds $f(x)\leq \liminf f(x_k)$ for any sequence $x_k\to x$.